# No such instance field: 'mLastLocation'

Tags: android, firebase

tengo el siguiente codigo y ale llegar a la parte de geoFire.setLocation...
en el debug me indica:

> No such instance field: 'mLastLocation'   No such instance field:
>   'geoFire'

```
private void displayLocation() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation != null) {
        if(location_switch.isChecked())
        {
            final double latitude=mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            final double longitude=mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            //update to firebase

            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                    if(mCurrent!=null)
                    {
                        mCurrent.remove();
                        mCurrent=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                        .title("Estas Aqui"));

                        // move camera to this position
                       // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));
                        // draw animation rotate marker
                        rotateMarker(mCurrent,-360,mMap);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }else
    {
        Log.d("Error EntregasLua","No se pudo obtener tu ubicacion");
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio diego, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Agrega tu clase completa por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que no tienes declaradas estas dos variables:
`mLastLocation` y `geoFire`

Es decir las estás llamando para asignarle el valor,  pero no las encuentra declardas en la clase.

`mLastLocation` debe ser de tipo `Location`

**`Location mLastLocation;`**

`geoFire` debe ser de tipo `GeoFire`

**`GeoFire geoFire;`**

Comment: En el caso de no estar declaradas las variables se muestra el error **"Cannot  find symbol variable" o "Cannot resolve symbol"**.